# What can I do to shrink the space between my CardViews within a RecyclerView?

Tags: android

So I'm learning app development for Android, and I'm a bit stuck. I'm trying to make a RecyclerView with CardViews, but there is just too much space between CardViews. [This is what it looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDgvA.png)

I'm going for more of the look that the Google app has with the feed.
 [This is more like what I'm shooting for.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qi2PU.jpg)

Anyways, I've searched and searched on this website for a solution to my problem and nothing seems to be working for me. I'm hoping that someone can give me something that will actually work.

Here's the xml for my cardview:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="10dp">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
    app:cardElevation="5dp"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="16dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/note_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
            android:layout_below="@+id/event_time"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/note_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/note_title" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I decrease the space between cards in a CardView within a RecyclerView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43299956/how-do-i-decrease-the-space-between-cards-in-a-cardview-within-a-recyclerview)

Comment: Try reducing these:
   app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
   app:cardElevation="5dp"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The top and bottom spaces is caused by your padding
android:paddingBottom="10dp", remove this or reduce it

Answer (score 0):

Decrease the PadingBotom of the root constraintLayout
  you could put 3 or 4 dp instead of 10dp.

```
android:paddingBottom="10dp"
```

Also I do not know if the copy of your code was not good ... the constraintLayout must close at the end:
after this:

```
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

you must have this:

```
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

From [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/CardView.html) for `CardView`:

> Before Lollipop, `CardView` adds padding to its content and draws shadows to that area. ... If you want `CardView` to add inner padding on platforms Lollipop and after as well, you can call `setUseCompatPadding(boolean)` and pass `true`.

In your layout, you have this attribute on your `CardView` tag:

```
app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
```

This does the same thing as the method in the quote above.

As a result, even if you had zero margin on all sides of your cards, users would still see space in between them because of the inner padding behavior. If you want really tight spacing, you'll have to remove this attribute (though of course you'll *still* get the larger spacing pre-Lollipop).